# Scaling Spring on Heroku

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku

I was wondering if someone could point me to a good tutorial or blog post on writing a spring application that can be all run in a single process for integration testing locally but when deployed will deploy different subsystems into different processes/dynos on heroku.

For example, I have services for User management, Job processing, etc. all in my web application. I want to run it just as a web application locally. But when I deploy to heroku I want to deploy just the stateless web front end to TWO dynos and then have worker dynos that I can select different services to run on. I may decide to group 2 of these services into one process or decide that each should run in its own process. Obviously when the services run in their own process they will need to transparently add some kind of transport like REST or RabbitMQ or AKKA or some such.

Any pointers on where to start looking to learn how to do this? Or am I thinking about this incorrectly and you'd like to suggest a different approach? I need to figure out how to setup the application and also how to construct maven and intellij to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't point you to a prefabricated article or post, but I can share the direction I started down to solve a similar problem. Essentially, the proposed approach was similar to yours - put specific services with potentially long-running logic in worker dynos and pass messages via Jesque (Java port of Resque) on a RedisToGo instance (Heroku add-on). I never got the separate web vs. worker Spring contexts fully ironed out (moved on to other priorities) but the gist of it was 1) web tier app context would be configured to post messages and 2) worker app context configured to consume.

That said, I used `foreman` locally to simulate the Heroku environment to debug scaling (`foreman start --formation="web=2"` + Apache `mod_proxy_http`). Big Spring gotcha when you scale to 2+ dynos - make sure you are using Redis or Memcache for session storage when using `webapp-runner`. Spring uses `HttpSession` by default to store the security context... no session affinity or native Tomcat session replication.

Final caveat - in our case, none of our worker processing needed to be reflected to the end user. That said, we were using Pusher for other features (also a Heroku add-on). If you need to update the user when an async task completes, I recommend looking at it.